# scoped_ptr for double pointers

Tags: boost, double-pointer, scoped-ptr

Is there a halfway elegant way to upgrade to following code snipped by the use of boost's scoped_ptr or scoped_array?

```
MyClass** dataPtr = NULL;
dataPtr = new MyClass*[num];
memset(dataPtr, 0, sizeof(MyClass*));
allocateData(dataPtr); // allocates objects under all the pointers

// have fun with the data objects

// now I'm bored and want to get rid of them
for(uint i = 0; i < num; ++i)
  delete dataPtr[i];
delete[] dataPtr;
```

Comment: Can you modify allocateData()?

Comment: In theory I could but since a lot of old code uses this function the way it is, I'm very hesitant to doing so and would prefer a solution without modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way now:

```
boost::scoped_array<MyClass*> dataPtr(new MyClass*[num]);
memset(dataPtr.get(), 0, num * sizeof(MyClass*));
allocateData(dataPtr.get());
```

Seems to work fine.

Comment: You will still need to deallocate all elements in the array manually.

Comment: Yeah, I just recognized with Visual Leak Detector that the inner pointers won't be deleted. I guess I'd have to nest scoped_ptrs to do so. I guess I'll just stay with a manual delete then.

Comment: Just rewrite `allocateData`. The function is a perfect case of horrible design.